# wp_enqueue_script() doesn't work with AJAX

Tags: ajax, wp-enqueue-script, wp-register-script

My problem is: I made an AJAX call using this code

```php
wp_enqueue_script( 'prefix-myscript-name', plugins_url( 'js/ajaxcall.js', __FILE__ ) );
```

I made the call and the AJAX just going fine. I used this code:

```php
add_action( 'wp_ajax_ajax_action', 'ajax_response' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_ajax_action', 'ajax_response' );

function ajax_response(){
    wp_enqueue_script( 'prefix-myscript-call', plugins_url( 'js/myscript.js', __FILE__ ) );
}
```

I used an `alert('Test')` in `ajaxcall.js` but it's not showing up!

I'm disappointed. Any Solution?

Comment: what are you expecting to happen exactly? you can't enqueue a js file in an ajax callback, that doesn't really make any sense. it would help to back up a few steps and explain what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: What will happen if i tried this?! `echo '<script src="js/myscript.js" type="text/javascript"></script>'` That will make it, But manual way!, What im trying to do is to enqueue the js file using wp_enqueue_script(), Why cant i use wp_enqueue_script inside the ajax response ?

Comment: Look, wp_enqueue_script in classic way needs `wp_head` to be executecd. And the execution means echoing <script src="..."></sc..> in header.php (mostly). If you want to use a script, say, when ajax is successful, use http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/, for when you enqueue it, it never gets displayed. Your ajax calls should be getting/setting data and returning a meaningful response, i.e. array, boolean value, string value…  >That will make it, But manual way!,> Why do not you enqueue it through functions.php?

Comment: Ok thank you @IvanHanák That was useful, I dont want the script to be used anyway, the script will be used inside "If statement" and "Loop" so in some cases there is no need to include the js file, The point of trying to use wp_enqueue_script is because this function prevent multi execution for the same script (If the script is included then, the script dont have to be included again), I wounder whats the point of enqueuing it through functions.php ?

Comment: So you do not have to do it manual way :) The point is, WordPress created this function so that you have a 'improved' control over adding scripts, styles into your theme. For instance adding dependencies, it means, you tell wordpress to display certain script only after jQuery was displayed, or through boolean variable you decide whether a script displays in header or footer (yes, you would have to cut it from header.p and paste into footer.php :-D). It is pretty good stuff, have a look http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script